# Nested join query with createCriteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails 3.x. I have these simple domain:

```
class Classification {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [instrument: Instrument, ptf: Portfolio]
}

class Instrument {

   Long internalId
   String name

   static hasOne = [classification: Classification]
   static hasMany = [analisys: Analisys]
}

class Analisys {

   Instrument instrument
   int serialId

}
```

I'm trying to perform this query:

```
  def results = Classification.createCriteria().list() {
        ptf {
            eq("id", 10l)
        }
        instrument {
            analisys{
                  eq("serialId", 5)
             }
        }
        instrument {
                eq("name", "testName")
            }

    return results
}
```

it works, but the constraint eq("serialId", 5) is not taken in consideration at all. Any idea?

thanks

I change the query like this and it works even if CriteriaSpecification is deprecated

```
   def results = Classification.createCriteria().list() {
        ptf {
            eq("id", 10l)
        }
        instrument {
          eq("name", "testName")

          analisys(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN){
                  eq("serialId", 5)
             }
        }
    return results
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `eq("name", "testName")` into the previous closure of `instrument` but before/after the `analisys` closure. That way you only have one `instrument` closure within your criteria?

Comment: thanks for the hit, I just try: no luck

Comment: You can use `JoinType` instead of `CriteriaSpecification` since it's deprecated. Here is the [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/deprecated-list.html)